# How to make source function that polls an http endpoint into flink stream for every 1 hour?

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to have a source which poll http endpoint every 1 hour and keep that as flink source to broadcast to operators.

I tried to make it as simple function but seems not working as expected.

Code is :

```html
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SourceFunction
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SourceFunction.SourceContext
import org.apache.http.{HttpRequest, HttpResponse}
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity
import org.apache.http.impl.bootstrap.{HttpServer, ServerBootstrap}
import org.apache.http.protocol.{HttpContext, HttpRequestHandler}

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

class HttpStreamFun(url: String) extends SourceFunction[String] {

  @transient private var server: HttpServer = _

  override def run(ctx: SourceContext[String]): Unit = {
    server = ServerBootstrap
      .bootstrap()
      .registerHandler(
        url,
        new HttpRequestHandler() {
          override def handle(req: HttpRequest,
                              rep: HttpResponse,
                              context: HttpContext): Unit = {
            ctx.collect(req.getRequestLine.getUri)
            rep.setStatusCode(200)
            rep.setEntity(new StringEntity("OK"))
          }
        }
      )
      .create()
    server.start()
    server.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
  }

  override def cancel(): Unit = {
    server.stop()
  }

}
```

Main job has these to add the source as datastream:

```html
val text: DataStream[String] = env.addSource(new HttpStreamFun(config.baseUri))

text.print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use BroadcastStream

For more information, refer to
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/broadcast_state/

Comment: is there a way to broadcast from an api ?